Transfer Inbound REST API request from one Org to another Org
We have two Salesforce Orgs. At present the Org1 is receiving an inbound API request from the external system. The API request is a Salesforce standard composite API and posting platform event content in the request body. There is a trigger that listens the event and runs the business process.
For some reason, We need to transfer the API request from Org1 to Org2. i.e. As soon as Org1 receives the request, we would like to redirect the request to Org2 assuming the trigger is present in Org2 to complete the workflow.
Without any licensed tools like Mulesoft Anypoint or any connectors, I am thinking of the below options:

Authenticate Org2 from Org1 using OAuth mechanism and construct standard HTTP POST. The POST call will publish the event and the listener(trigger) in Org2 will process the workflow.

Expose a REST resource in Org2. Authenticate Org2 from Org1 and invoke the Rest resource by passing the payload as parameter. The Rest resource in Org2 receives the request and construct the event and publish the same.


Are there any additional ways to transfer the request from one org to another org.
